# Get place location with google places api

Tags: google-maps, google-places-api

I am trying to get a json list of places as seen in [this](https://developers.google.com/places/documentation/autocomplete) link. The only extra thing  I want that for each place that is suggested in the list I will get it's latitude and longitude.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The linked example is related to places-autocomplete. When you really need these data(especially the predictions) you must use the `reference` of the returned places  and send further requests for each place to retrieve the [place-details](https://developers.google.com/places/documentation/details#PlaceDetailsRequests)(which contain the geometry for this place)

When you don't need the predictions use [places-search](https://developers.google.com/places/documentation/search#PlaceSearchResponses) instead of places-autocomplete.